# Elaeagnus angustifolia

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

What do you call this fruit:

[image]

It's scientific name is **Elaeagnus angustifolia**; the only word I found for it is **Russian Olive**, but I doubt it is the word a native would say!

Comment: In my limited experience, the only native speakers who know what these are are people familiar with Persian culture, and thus use the Persian word: *senjed*

Answer (score 5):

Given this [USDA Article](https://www.invasivespeciesinfo.gov/profile/russian-olive), it does seem that Russian Olive is the colloquial term in the US.

This would be similar usage to [Kalamata Olives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalamata_olive), although in the US I have used (and have heard others use) the term Greek Olives instead, as "Greek" is a lot simpler than remembering "Kalamata". "Russian", by contrast, is a familiar term, so I would not be surprised to hear "Russian Olives" in the US.